# Won't Seven of Nine get tired legs or feet?

Tags: character, star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Won't Seven of Nine from *Star Trek: Voyager* get tired legs or feet from standing almost continuously, even when regenerating?

I could imagine a borg drone not getting tired legs because of all the metal implants supporting the organic parts of its body, but Seven of Nine's implants are almost all removed.

Answer (score 3):

The strong impression given is that when Seven regenerates in her alcove, it also helps her to recover the strength in her limbs that normal humans would gain from lying down to sleep.

> **JANEWAY:** *Consider it done. The Doctor tells me you don't need to regenerate any more. I can arrange some quarters for you, unless you
>   enjoy curling up in the Cargo Bay.*
>
> **SEVEN:** *A bed would be more comfortable. Since I arrived on Voyager, your guidance has been invaluable. Thank you, Captain.* - <sub><sup>[Voy: Human Error](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/715.htm)</sup></sub>

You may also wish to note that her blood is still filled with nanites that constantly repair her physical systems as well as a host of larger borg components (a "bi-radial socket" is mentioned). On at least one occasion ([Voy: Hunters](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/413.htm)) we learn that she's gone over 56 hours without sleeping with only minimal ill-effects, so clearly she's not quite fully human yet.